# Throw inside a callback inside a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, throw

I know that stackoverflow is full of similar question and I've read a lot of them.

From what I got a `throw` inside a promise should reject it, as I can read in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise):

> If the executor throws an exception, its value will be passed to the reject resolving function.

But even after read a lot of post about promises and throw I still don't understand the snippet of code I'm pasting and why it happens.

```
function foo(a, b, cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb('Inner error *!?"$%&#@"');
  }, 0);
}

const getThePromise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const cb = (err) => {

      /* >>> ************ */

      throw err;       // catch not called
      // reject(err);  // catch called

      /* ************ <<< */

    }
    foo('foo', 'dudee', cb);
  });
}

getThePromise()
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('CATCH:', err);
})
.then((res) => {
  console.log('then...');
})
```

I don't understand why if I use the `throw` the `.catch` of the promise is not called but if I use the `reject` it is called.

Just for sake of clarification I'm using Node.js v6.2.2 in a Mac OS/X 10.11 but I don't think it could be also a browser issue.

Comment: Put `.error((err) => {
  console.log('ERROR:', err);
})` too there

Comment: @Shaharyar, native Promise.prototype doesn't have `error` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Promise_prototype)

Comment: `throw` rejects promise if it's called synchronously only. remove your `setTimeout` and it will work. In async case use `reject`.

Comment: "If the executor throws an exception" - not your case. Your executor doesn't throw. Try `new Promise(() => {throw new Error('test')}).catch( e => console.log(e))`

Comment: Why do you want to Throw the error? That is the whole point of the `reject` method.

Answer (score 8):

You are throwing your error inside an asynchronous `setTimeout` call, which will lead to an uncaught error. The asynchronous code will not execute in the same context as the try-catch block. This has nothing to do with the promise API. This is just part of the behavior of asynchronous code execution in JavaScript.

Take a look at the following example.

```js
const asyncOperation = err => {
  try {
    setTimeout(function() {
      throw err; // will be dropped onto the event queue
      // until the call stack is empty
      // even if this takes longer than
      // a second.
    }, 1000);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e) // will not be called
  }
}

asyncOperation('Inner error *!?"$%&#@"')
```

And now the same example with the try-catch block inside the `setTimeout` call  and the error being thrown inside the try block.

```js
const asyncOperation = err => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    try {
      throw err // here the error will be throw inside
    } catch (e) { // the try block and has the same execution 
      console.log(e) // context.
    }
  }, 1000);
}

asyncOperation('Inner error *!?"$%&#@"')
```

You can find more information regarding the `Promise.catch` right here.

> ### [Promise.prototype.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)
>
> *The catch() method returns a Promise and deals with rejected cases only.*

There is actually an example with the same situation you are describing in your example. Check out

[**Gotchas when throwing errors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#Gotchas_when_throwing_errors)

```
// Errors thrown inside asynchronous functions will act like uncaught errors
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    throw 'Uncaught Exception!';
  }, 1000);
});

p2.catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e); // This is never called
});
```